# How to find my libGDX version?

Tags: libgdx, version

I started developing my game few years ago, with big pauses. There was no gradle back then, just simple java installation app. How can I find what is the version of LibGDX used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Gdx.app.log("Gdx version", com.badlogic.gdx.Version.VERSION);
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Xoppa is correct but I find it a very uncomfortable way of checking versions. It would be nice if the LibGDX setup tool and the big website download button showed the version number since currently (as far as I am aware of) the only way to know the version is to create a project first and I find that rather obscure.

A way to know without executing any code is to check the `build.gradle` file which "should" display the correct version number at line `gdxVersion = 'x.x.x'`.

Answer (score 0):

In any I.D.E., e.g. IntelliJ, AndroidStudio etc., create a temporary class to run System.out.printf()

```
public class printGdxVersion{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf(com.badlogic.gdx.Version.VERSION);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also find it in the project build.gradle file under:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "BibleQuiz"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.12'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.11'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.3'
        aiVersion = '1.8.2'
    }
```